# What does the error “undefined reference to 'dlopen'” mean?

Tags: compiling, raspberry-pi, gcc, libraries, error-handling

When I want to compile my c-file I get these messages:

```
undefined reference to 'dlopen'
undefined reference to 'dlsym'
```

In some other posts about this topic the solution was to add `-ldl` to the linker options or to the Command-line with `gcc test.c -ldl`. But this does not work. In this case i just get a .o file or a.out in the directory but I am not able to execute these files. When i am typing ./a.out in the command line, the error `segmentation fault` occurs. 
That is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "PI_GCS2_DLL_PF.h"
int main(){
   void* hPI_Dll = dlopen("test.so", RTLD_NOW);
   int ID = -1;
   PFPI_ConnectRS232ByDevName = (PI_ConnectRS232ByDevName);
   PI_ConnectRS232ByDevName = (PFPI_ConnectRS232ByDevName) dlsym(hPI_Dll, "PI_ConnectRS232ByDevName");

...
}
```

I am developing on the RockPI 4 (on Linux) that is very similar to the Raspberry PI. So how to fix this "error"? Do I have to install any libraries maybe?

Comment: Welcome to the site. The "solution" you already found actually _does_ solve the problem of your error messages. However, this alone is insufficient in getting an executable file in many cases. In order to understand which of theses cases applies to you, we need to know by what mechanism you are compiling your C code: if you use a `Makefile`, please post the contents and the target you called. If you use a single command-line, please include that in your question.

Comment: @AdminBee Hey, I use the Command: `gcc test.c -ldl`

Comment: I see. Please edit your question to include that information; it will help other contributors in investigating your problem.

Comment: You are on an older UNIX variant tat did not yet integrate `dlopen()` into `libc`, so you need to use `-ldl` on the linker command line. Typically, `dlopen` has been integrated into `libc` approx. 20 years ago....but if you already use it, mmm?

Comment: Hey @schily, I used `-ldl` but after that I got an a.out - file and i am not able to run it

Comment: @schily The OP is running a Linux variant. Even on modern linux installations, the manpage to `dlopen` says "Link with `-ldl`".

Comment: @AlexanderZ. If you have an `a.out` file then your program compiled.  `a.out` is the name that gcc gives to your program when you don't tell gcc what to name it.  The problem you need to solve now is why you can't run it.  What command did you type to try to run it and what was the error.  You can [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Hey, thank, i changed it

Comment: This means that something in your program itself has a problem, and the question is better asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AdminBee!

Comment: You're not checking the return value of dlopen() or dlsym(), each of which may fail. In particular, dlopen() may not look for test.so in the current directory, may not find it in its default path, and may return a NULL handle. If you go on and use it nevertheless, your program will crash.

Comment: You fixed it. The program ran, the program triggered an exception in the kernel `segmentation fault`. This error is due to trying to access memory that you should not. E.g. A system call errored and returned `0` instead of a valid address. Your program did not check for errors and tried to access memory at address `0`.